# Filtering JTable using JTextField and DocumentListener very unresponsive and laggy

Tags: java, swing

I have an application that holds data inside a JTable Component. I am filtering the table based on text I enter inside a JTextField that has a DocumentListener attached. For some reason, the responsiveness of that filter is very slow. Whenever I type a new character inside the textfield, the application seems to freeze for a bit. Is there any way I can improove this or maybe I am doing it wrong after all? Initially I thought it is due to the fact that I have several custom Renderers attached which could have deceased performance, but after commenting them all out there is still no change noticeable so I can rule that out.

This is where I create and attach the listener.

```
private void initListener() {
    this.searchField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String text = searchField.getText();
            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
            }
            table.repaint();
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String text = searchField.getText();
            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
            }
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            String text = searchField.getText();
            if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(null);
            } else {
                table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
            }
        }
    });
```

This is my Table class configuration

```
    private void initializeUI() {
    this.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    this.getColumn("INTERVAL").setPreferredWidth(20);
}

private void setCustomRowSorter() {
    this.rowSorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
    this.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

}
private void setTableCellRenderers() {
    this.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTickerTableRenderer());
    this.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setCellRenderer(new RSICellRenderer());
    this.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setCellRenderer(new SMACellRenderer());
    this.getColumnModel().getColumn(8).setCellRenderer(new SMACellRenderer());
    this.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setCellRenderer(new SMACellRenderer());
}
```

In case of relevance, here are the custom CellRenderers used by this table. Removing them does not seem to improve performance.

```
public class DefaultTickerTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
private final JCheckBox ckb = new JCheckBox();

public DefaultTickerTableRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true); //MUST do this for background to show up.
}

public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    JComponent c = (JComponent) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    c.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
    if (!isSelected) {
        if (row % 2 == 0) {
            c.setBackground(AppColors.TICKER_TABLE_DEFAULT_BG);
        } else {
            c.setBackground(AppColors.TICKERTABLE_STRIPE_BG);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
}

public class SMACellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
private Market market;

public SMACellRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
    float closePrice = Float.parseFloat(table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 5).toString());
    float smaValue = Float.parseFloat(value.toString());
    if (smaValue < closePrice) {
        setBackground(AppColors.TICKERTABLE_GREEN);
    } else if (smaValue > closePrice) {
        setBackground(AppColors.TICKERTABLE_RED);
    } else {
        setBackground(AppColors.TICKERTABLE_NEUTRAL);
    }
    if (isSelected) {
        setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    }
    setText(value.toString());
    return this;
}
}

public class RSICellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
private Market market;

public RSICellRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);
}

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, Color.BLACK));
    float rsiValue = Float.parseFloat(value.toString());
    if (rsiValue < TechnicalAnalytics.RSI_OVERSOLD_THRESHOLD) {
        setBackground(AppColors.TICKERTABLE_GREEN);
    } else if (rsiValue > TechnicalAnalytics.RSI_OVERBOUGHT_THRESHOLD) {
        setBackground(AppColors.TICKERTABLE_RED);
    } else {
        setBackground(AppColors.TICKERTABLE_NEUTRAL);
    }
    if (isSelected) {
        setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    }
    setText(value.toString());
    return this;
}
}
```

Solution
Got it to work by using this approach.

```
 private void initListener() {
    Runnable task = () -> {
        String text = searchField.getText();
        if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
            table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
            table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
        }
    };

    searchField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(
            new DocumentListener() {
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    newFilter();
                }

                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    newFilter();
                }

                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    newFilter();
                }
            });
}

private void newFilter() {
    RowFilter<TickerTableModel, Object> rf = null;
    try {
        rf = RowFilter.regexFilter(searchField.getText(), 0);
    } catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return;
    }
    table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(rf);
}
```

Comment: (1-) Still waiting for an [mre]. The MRE should be the code with default renderers to minimize the size of the code. No need for the repaint() since this will be done automatically. See: [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for complete working examples.

Comment: this question has nothing to do with any other question, no MRE required here. Question is obvious, relevant methods placed into the question.

Comment: The point is you continue to ask questions without posting an MRE even though you have been asked previously to post an MRE with every question. Many times when creating the MRE the problem is found.  Until the problem is solved you don't know what is or isn't relevant to the statement problem. Most often the problem is with code not posted. Voting to close since you aren't willing to provide the necessary information needed to help solve the problem.

Comment: The project is way to big in order to be able to code something up that is reproducable. It is heavily integrated with 3rd party APIs and websocket data which produces the content for the table. I know how to work with a basic JTable. I can post all of the code but that is too much for here I believe. There are no performance issues besides when using the searchfield for filtering, that is why I am at least assuming somewhere there might be the issue (hence posting relevant methods).

Comment: *The project is way to big in order to be able to code something up that is reproducable.* - which is why you create an MRE. *3rd party APIs and websocket data which produces the content for the table.* - which are completely irrelevant to the stated problem. Your problem is filtering. So the MRE just needs hard coded data. Did you read the tutorial??? It has an MRE with hard coded data. Does it cause a problem? Does your real table have more rows of data? Post an MRE that simulates the problem if you want help. We can't guess the problem since the tutorial shows how this normally works.

Comment: Ok I will do thank you

Comment: I specifically stated the MRE should be done with default renderers and the only update you make is to include the renderer code??? Again the point of the MRE is to remove possible problem code and use default classes. If the MRE works as expected then you start to add back in custom classes to see if they cause the issue.

Comment: Originally the table holds arround 500 objects. I tested the application with only 50 data objects inside the table and the filtering is very smooth. So must be the amount of data that is driving the application to be unresponsive.

Comment: I modified the filter example from the tutorial link I provided to contain 500 rows of data. The filtering is immediate for me.

Comment: the tutorials does not seem to include any usages of document listeners tho

Comment: I gave an example that works with a documentlistener, the tutorial does not use any documentlistener. Thank you, you are not obligated to participate on this post.

Comment: I did not see the small link refering the java example which then contained the documentlistener. I used that code and everything seems to work fine. Updated the post with the solution. Thank you. I still dont know the difference between my initial code tho, everything seemed very similar.

Comment: *I gave an example that works with a documentlistener,* - no you didn't. You did NOT post any code that we can copy/paste/compile/test to see the described behaviour. *you are not obligated to participate* Its not about me participating. Its about you participating. Everybody who attempts to answer questions donates their time to help others. The least you can do is create a proper MRE with each question to verify that you indeed do have a problem and are not making a careless mistake. The MRE gives us all the information we need to attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a good idea to wait until the user pauses their typing before updating your row filter, instead of updating the filter right away for every document change.  You can do this using a [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html):

```
this.searchField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    private final Timer updater = new Timer(250, e -> {
        String text = searchField.getText();
        if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
            table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
            table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(
                RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(text)));
        }
    });

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updater.restart();
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updater.restart();
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        updater.restart();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing the work on a different thread to the main UI thread.

Eg:

```java
private void initListener() {
    Runnable task = () -> {
        String text = searchField.getText();
        if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
            table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
            table.getRowSorter().setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));
        }
        table.repaint();
    };
    this.searchField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(task);
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(task);
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(task);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: This code still uses the EDT. That is the point of using invokeLater(...). It places the code on the EDT.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that solution but no difference noticed.